# SQL with table as becomes ambiguous

Tags: postgresql

Perhaps I'm approaching this all wrong, in which case feel free to point out a better way to solve the overall question, which "How do I use an intermediate table for future queries?"

Let's say I've got tables `foo` and `bar`, which join on some `baz_id`, and I want to use combine this into an intermediate table to be fed into upcoming queries. I know of the `WITH .. AS (...)` statement, but am running into problems as such:

```
WITH foobar AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM foo
    INNER JOIN bar ON bar.baz_id = foo.baz_id
)
SELECT
    baz_id
    -- some other things as well
FROM
    foobar
```

The issue is that (Postgres 9.4) tells me `baz_id is ambiguous`. I understand this happens because `SELECT *` includes all the columns in both tables, so `baz_id` shows up twice; but I'm not sure how to get around it. I was hoping to avoid copying the column names out individually, like

```
SELECT
    foo.var1, foo.var2, foo.var3, ...
    bar.other1, bar.other2, bar.other3, ...
FROM foo INNER JOIN bar ...
```

because there are hundreds of columns in these tables.

Is there some way around this I'm missing, or some altogether different way to approach the question at hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH foobar AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM foo
    INNER JOIN bar USING(baz_id)
)
SELECT
    baz_id
    -- some other things as well
FROM
    foobar
```

It leaves only one instance of the `baz_id` column in the select list.

[From the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html)

> The USING clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an equality comparison for each one. For example, joining T1 and T2 with USING (a, b) produces the join condition ON T1.a = T2.a AND T1.b = T2.b.
>
> Furthermore, the output of JOIN USING suppresses redundant columns: there is no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must have equal values. While JOIN ON produces all columns from T1 followed by all columns from T2, JOIN USING produces one output column for each of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any remaining columns from T1, followed by any remaining columns from T2.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed, and appreciate the doc-quote as well!